# Using WSGI on Redhat Linux

Tags: python, package, redhat

I wanted to install WSGI on a RedHat linux box in order to make a Python server interface, but the only way I could find to do that was to use `modwsgi`, which is an Apache module. The whole reason I'm using WSGI is that I don't want to use Apache, so this kinda defeats the purpose.

Does anyone know of actual WSGI packages for RedHat linux or is this the only way?

----Edit----

I just found out that WSGI is built into Python 2.5 and higher, so I don't need to install anything. I don't know how to mark this question as solved without answering it myself. Any tips will be appreciated.

Comment: To mark it as answered, simply add your own answer below and accept it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found out that WSGI is included in Python 2.5 and above, so you don't need to do any installs. Just say things like `from wsgiref import make_server`.

Answer (score 0):

You can also run something like [uwsgi](http://projects.unbit.it/uwsgi/). It runs as a server on either a file or TCP socket, and you can hook into it with any web server you wish. I personally use Cherokee, but Apache or nginx, or anything else can use it too.

Answer (score 0):

WSGI is a protocol. In order to use it you need a WSGI container such as mod_wsgi, Paste Deploy, CherryPy, or wsgiref.